# How to retrieve duplicated data from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have in my database a table that Continent users ,the first field is NAME and this name can be duplicated .
I want to retrieve user's name . for example if i have in my table the name John 3 time and David 2 time and Katy 1 time,
I want the result to be john David Katy ,
If the name are duplicated i want to escape it ,and display just names once for every name, i want to do this using PHP and MYSQLI .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column with many duplicate values and only want to list the unique values you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to only return those,

```
SELECT DISTINCT `NAME` FROM `TABLE_NAME`
```